# bottom toolbar is not showing in gridview list

Tags: android

I want to apply the bottom toolbar but I am running my app and is not showing

```
 private ActionMenuView amvMenu;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        Listitem = new ArrayList<Listitem>();
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        GetDataJSON gj = new GetDataJSON();
        gj.execute();
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

     //   getData();
        initToolbars();
    }
```

this is initoolbars method

```
private void initToolbars() {

    Toolbar toolbarBottom = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom);
    toolbarBottom.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            return true;
        }
    });
    // Inflate a menu to be displayed in the toolbar
    toolbarBottom.inflateMenu(R.menu.main);
}
```

I guess the problem here I am setting adapter

```
GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, Listitem);
     //   gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter); 
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

       list.setAdapter(adapter);
```